# Missing navigation bar on views controllers

Tags: ios, xcode, uinavigationcontroller

im working with navigation bar in Xcode,
I add navigation bar but in my views don't show:

My storyboard

[image]

But my view on simulator

[image]

And my config

[image]

What im doing wrong??

Answer (score 1):

The values in the **Simulated Metrics** section affect only what you see in Interface Builder; they are *completely ignored* at runtime. You're not seeing a navigation bar because you probably didn't push your view controller onto a navigation controller instance (`UINavigationController.pushViewController(_:animated:)`). Coincidentally, you're seeing a blank space where you *think* the nav bar should be because you've specified that much vertical empty space above the "Presione..." line in the storyboard.

Note that you don't have to push your view controller into a navigation controller manually, because you've specified it as the `rootViewController` of a navigation controller in the storyboard. Present your navigation controller, and it will push the root view controller automatically.